# new a object takes a lot of time

Tags: c++, qt

I needed to implement an interface software, but there was a bad lag after clicking a button.After investigation, the problem was found in this step.
I am trying new a object but this step takes About 8000 milliseconds.

```
LineTrend *lineTrend = new LineTrend(this);
strFileData = lineTrend->editHtmlFile(ui, strFileData);
```

The code for this class

```
#include "TrendConfig.h"
#include <QMessageBox>

class LineTrend : public TrendConfig
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    LineTrend(QWidget *parent);
    ~LineTrend();

public:
    virtual QString editHtmlFile(const Ui::TrendConfigClass &ui, QString &strFileData);
    virtual QString editHtmlTemplateFile(const Ui::TrendConfigClass &ui);
    virtual QString editHtmlTemplateFile(const Ui::TrendConfigClass &ui, QTreeWidgetItem *itemPre);

};
```

This is part of the base class code

```
class TrendConfig : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    TrendConfig(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    virtual ~TrendConfig();

    virtual QString editHtmlFile(const Ui::TrendConfigClass &ui, QString &strFileData) { return NULL;};
    virtual QString editHtmlTemplateFile(const Ui::TrendConfigClass &ui){ return NULL;};
    virtual QString editHtmlTemplateFile(const Ui::TrendConfigClass &ui,QTreeWidgetItem *itemPre){ return NULL;};
}
```

The implementation function looks like this

```
LineTrend::LineTrend(QWidget *parent)
    : TrendConfig(parent)
{
}

LineTrend::~LineTrend()
{
}

QString LineTrend::editHtmlFile(const Ui::TrendConfigClass &ui, QString &strFileData)
{
    //获得趋势组名并替换
    QTreeWidgetItem *item = ui.trendWidget->currentItem();
    if (item != NULL)
    {
        QString strQtTrendGroupName = item->text(0);
        strFileData.replace("trendGroup", strQtTrendGroupName);

        //生成随机数据
        QString strQtTrendData;

        QTreeWidgetItemIterator it(ui.listWidget);
        while (*it)
        {
            QString strQtAppendTrendData = QString("{ data: [%1, %2, %3, %4, %5, %6, %7],type: 'line'},")
                .arg(qrand()).arg(qrand()).arg(qrand()).arg(qrand()).arg(qrand()).arg(qrand()).arg(qrand());
            strQtTrendData.append(strQtAppendTrendData);
            it++;
        }

        //去掉最后一个字符
        strQtTrendData = strQtTrendData.left(strQtTrendData.length() - 1);

        //替换趋势数据
        strFileData.replace("trendData", strQtTrendData);

        return strFileData;
    }
    else
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this, GBK::ToUnicode("信息提示"), GBK::ToUnicode("请选择趋势组选项，否则无法进行预览"));
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

What causes that new a object taks so much time.and how can it be improved？thanks

Comment: The constructor `LineTrend(QWidget *parent);` or the call `LineTrend::editHtmlFile` but because you did not post what is in them, I cannot be more precise.

Comment: The member functions in the derived class don't need to be virtual - unless the derived class is a base of another class, in which case its' dtor should also be virtual. Also, if you wanted to utilize polymorphism, shouldn't you create the object like this: `TrendConfig *foo = new LineTrend(this)`. Might as well switch to smart pointers. But I agree with @Quimby, that we need more details to figure out what's going on. I guess you could comment out line by line the body of the ctor and see where the problem is.

Comment: Please show a [mcve], something in your code is taking time, what it is we can't tell without seeing it

Comment: It's plausible 8s is just how long it takes to do all the requisite processing